# Servlet response write vs print? Which is better?

Tags: java, servlets

I am having a string which needs to be sent as response from a servlet & I am having two approaches to send response back from it.

First is using PrintWriter.

> response.getWriter().print(responseString);

Second is using OutputStream.

```
 byte[] byteResponse = responseString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 response.getOutputStream().write(byteResponse);
```

I want to know which is better and efficient way of sending response?

Please suggest.

Comment: Class.forName("UTF-8") is for encoding while sending response.

Comment: Sorry, typo here. Its Charset.forName("UTF-8") not Class.forName("UTF-8").

Answer (score 2):

Use an OutputStream for binary data, and a Writer for text.

Comment: Thanks. From servlet i am passing response to a class which further passes this response to UI. In this case, which way i should use in servlet to pass response to intermediate class because from intermediate class which is sending response to UI, i must pass response as string.

Answer (score 0):

**I am having a string** specifies that you wish to write a string so i suggest the PrintWriter object

```
 //prints text data to screen (browser)
 PrintWriter printer = response.getWriter();
 printer.print(string);
 //print again if you wish
 printer.print("Welcome blahblah");
 //close afterwards if you don't mind.
 printer.close();
```

so if you wish to write text to browser, PrintWriter works just fine, fast and simple.

Comment: Its three way process. I need to pass response to an intermediate class first and from this intermediate class, i need to render it on UI. So from servlet to intermediate class, which way should i take as while rendering on UI, i need to pass string only.